# how to group array of nsdictionary according to the value inside the element

Tags: ios, objective-c, filter, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I have array of dictionary that needs to be grouped according to PO which is part of the element and also get the total of quantityOrdered according to the same PO.
The PO is dynamic it means it can be any value that needs to be filtered and compute the quantityOrderd accordingly.

Please help.

```
{
    PO = PO2;
    QuantityReceived = 1;
},
{
    PO = PO1;
    QuantityReceived = 3;
},
{

    PO = PO1;
    QuantityReceived = 3;
},
{
    PO = PO3;
    QuantityReceived = 2;
},
{
    PO = PO2;
    QuantityReceived = 2;
},
{
    PO = PO3;
    QuantityReceived = 4;
},
{

    PO = PO1;
    QuantityReceived = 1;
},
```

Apology for the confusion or incomplete question but i need to create a new array of dictionary with similar like this :

```
{
   PO = PO1;
   TotalQuanityReceived=7;
   LineItems=3;
},
{
   PO = PO2;
   TotalQuanityReceived=3;
   LineItems=2;
},
{
   PO = PO3;
   TotalQuanityReceived=6;
   LineItems=2;
},
```

i updated my example and make it easy to read.

Comment: NSDictionarys do not maintain order of their elements where as NSArrays do.

Comment: Are you asking how to sort an array of NSDictionary based on the value of one of the keys?

Comment: question updated, thank you for the attention.

Comment: Maybe we would help more, if incoming quantities and outcoming totals in your example did match.

Comment: my bad i didn't saw the last row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (NSArray *)whatever:(NSArray *)dictionaries
{
    NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary *resultsByPO = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in dictionaries) {
        id po = [dictionary objectForKey:@"PO"];
        NSMutableDictionary *result = [resultsByPO objectForKey:po];

        if (result == nil) {
            result = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [resultsByPO setObject:result forKey:po];
            [results addObject:result];
            [result setObject:po forKey:@"PO"];
        }

        double total = [[result objectForKey:@"TotalQuantityReceived"] doubleValue];
        total += [[dictionary objectForKey:@"QuantityOrdered"] doubleValue];

        int count = 1 + [[result objectForKey:@"Count"] intValue];

        [result setObject:@(total) forKey:@"TotalQuantityReceived"];
        [result setObject:@(count) forKey:@"Count"];
    }
    return results;
}
```

More pain will come with PO values not conforming to `NSCopying`.

Comment: how we will know if the quantity received is for PO1 PO2 or PO3. thank you for your reply.

Comment: I don't know. It was your example with 'array of dicts' output format.

Comment: If you are asking about how this code works -- each 'result record' is cached by po-key and is reused when found in cache (otherwise it is created and added into results array and into cache as well).

Comment: thank you that was awesome, i will try it now. sorry i'm newbie. thank you again.

Comment: one more favor to ask how can i count the number of lines the particular PO appeared

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the clever way with KVC or the stupid easy way. Let's do it the stupid easy way!

Make an empty NSMutableDictionary. Let's call it `dict`.

Cycle through your array of dictionaries. For each dictionary:

1. Fetch its PO. Call that value `thisPO`.
2. Fetch `dict[thisPO]`. Was it nil?

   a. Yes. Okay, so this particular PO has not yet been encountered. Set `dict[thisPO]` to this dictionary's quantity received (as an NSNumber).

   b. No. Turn that value into an integer, add this dictionary's quantity received, and set the total back into `dict[thisPO]` (as an NSNumber).

Done! The result is not quite what you asked for; the result looks like this:

```
{
    PO1 = 100;
    PO2 = 120;
    ...
}
```

But now, you see, the work of totalling is done and it is easy to transform that into an array of dictionaries if that is what you want.

Comment: thank you matt but how can i ensure that all the POs PO1 will be totalled same with PO2?

Comment: That is what step 2b does.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this is what you are saying or not, but to sort an array of dictionaries based on one of the elements it would look something like this.

```
NSDictionary *d1 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       [NSNumber numberWithDouble:100],@"PO",
                       [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0], @"Category",
                       nil];

NSDictionary *d2 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    [NSNumber numberWithDouble:50],@"PO",
                    [NSNumber numberWithDouble:90], @"Category",
                    nil];

NSArray *unsorted = @[d1, d2];

NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [unsorted sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    NSDictionary *first = (NSDictionary*)a;
    NSDictionary *second = (NSDictionary*)b;

    NSNumber *firstPO = [first objectForKey:@"PO"];
    NSNumber *secondPO = [second objectForKey:@"PO"];

    return [firstPO  compare:secondPO];
}];

NSLog(@"unsorted = %@", unsorted);

NSLog(@"sorted = %@", sortedArray);
```

I wasn't really sure what PO was, so I just used an NSNumber as an example. Look at this page for an overview of how you would compare a customer object. http://nshipster.com/nssortdescriptor/.

Then you can loop through the array, now in the correct order and build your next NSDictionary.