# creating a dictionary summary base on array of nsdictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I have an array of dictionary that needs to be summarised based on the value inside. The PO row will be the grouping criteria which is dynamic.

It needs to count the number of element per PO and total the quantity received.

```
 {
    PO = PO2;
    QuantityReceived = 1;
},
{
    PO = PO1;
    QuantityReceived = 3;
},
{

    PO = PO1;
    QuantityReceived = 3;
},
{
    PO = PO3;
    QuantityReceived = 2;
},
{
    PO = PO2;
    QuantityReceived = 2;
},
{
    PO = PO3;
    QuantityReceived = 4;
},
{

    PO = PO1;
    QuantityReceived = 1;
},
```

sample output is:

```
{
   PO = PO1;
   TotalQuanityReceived=7;
   LineItems=3;
},
{
   PO = PO2;
   TotalQuanityReceived=3;
   LineItems=2;
},
{
   PO = PO3;
   TotalQuanityReceived=6;
   LineItems=2;
},
```

Comment: This looks identical to your previous question, for which you accepted an answer.

Comment: yes but i cannot figure out to get the line items.

Comment: don't really get lineItems... but i think it is just the distinct count of each POx

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to group array of nsdictionary according to the value inside the element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504990/how-to-group-array-of-nsdictionary-according-to-the-value-inside-the-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in short:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        //INPUT DATA
        NSArray *inputPos = @[ @{ @"PO":@"PO2", @"QuantityReceived":@1 },
        @{ @"PO":@"PO1", @"QuantityReceived":@3 },
        @{ @"PO":@"PO1", @"QuantityReceived":@3 },
        @{ @"PO":@"PO3", @"QuantityReceived":@2 },
        @{ @"PO":@"PO2", @"QuantityReceived":@2 },
        @{ @"PO":@"PO3", @"QuantityReceived":@4 },
        @{ @"PO":@"PO1", @"QuantityReceived":@1 }];

        //REAL LOGIC
        NSMutableArray *originalPOs = [inputPos mutableCopy];
        NSMutableArray *groupedPOs = [@[] mutableCopy];

        while(originalPOs.count) {
            NSArray *matchingPOs = [originalPOs filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"PO == %@", originalPOs[0] [@"PO"]]];
            [originalPOs removeObjectsInArray:matchingPOs];

            NSInteger sum = 0;
            NSArray *qs = [matchingPOs valueForKeyPath:@"QuantityReceived"];
            for(NSNumber *quantity in qs)
                sum += quantity.integerValue;

            [groupedPOs addObject:@{@"PO":matchingPOs[0][@"PO"], @"QuantityReceived":@(sum), @"LineItems":@(qs.count)}];
        }

        NSLog(@"%@", groupedPOs);
    }
}
```

Comment: wrapped in a runnable program, real logic is quite short

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a few ways. Can achieve it writing something like:

```
    NSString *mainKey = @"PO";
    NSString *totalKey = @"TotalQuantityReceived";
    NSString *quantityKey = @"QuantityReceived";
    NSString *lineItemsKey = @"LineItems";

    void (^updateDictionary)(NSMutableDictionary *, NSDictionary *) = ^(NSMutableDictionary *outputDictionary, NSDictionary *inputDictionary) {
        outputDictionary[totalKey] = @([outputDictionary[totalKey] integerValue] + [inputDictionary[quantityKey] integerValue]);
        outputDictionary[lineItemsKey] = @([outputDictionary[lineItemsKey] integerValue] + 1);
    };

     NSMutableArray *output = [NSMutableArray array];
    [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *dictionary, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        id key = dictionary[mainKey];
        NSDictionary *existingDictionary = [[output filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", mainKey, key]] lastObject];
        NSMutableDictionary *outputDictionary = [existingDictionary mutableCopy];
        if (!outputDictionary) {
            outputDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:key forKey:mainKey];
            updateDictionary(outputDictionary, dictionary);
            [output addObject:outputDictionary];
        } else {
            updateDictionary(outputDictionary, dictionary);
            [output replaceObjectAtIndex:[output indexOfObject:existingDictionary] withObject:outputDictionary];
        }
    }];

    [output sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *dictionary1, NSDictionary *dictionary2) {
        NSString *key1 = dictionary1[mainKey];
        NSString *key2 = dictionary2[mainKey];
        return [key1 compare:key2];
    }];
```

Comment: Thank you Maciej Oczko I need to learn your code first i was amaze by this. i'm certainly a newbie :)

Comment: this looks a tad complicated .. though im sure it will work. there is WAY too much sorting going on :D

Comment: Daij-Djan you're right. The code is open for optimization ;) Your solution is better.